Ghost file after antivirus removes it
I have a file that doesn't exist but is blocking anything else from existing with that name.
When I try to delete it with CMD - file doesn't exist.
When I try to rename any other file to this one - access is denied.
When I try to rename the folder it's in - the folder or file in it is open in another program.
The issue was created when I downloaded a file over FTP and BitDefender antivirus decided to banish it into ghost dimension.
I used takeown /r /f * and icacls * /reset to reset permissions/ownership of everything inside the folder but that didn't help the issue.

Could it be BitDefender is blocking the file, waiting for confirmation on what to do with it (Quarantine/Delete/Ignore) ?

@Silbee It's not displaying me anything, I clicked around and couldn't find anything either

First, try restarting the PC to see if the issue is fixed so that you can delete or rename the file.
If that does not fix your issue you will either have to manually delete or restore it using BitDefender.
If that still does not fix your issue boot into Windows Safe Mode and then try renaming the file or deleting it.
